# TypeError at /admin/imgUploader/images/add/

Tags: python, django

This is the models.py

```
from distutils.command.upload import upload
from email.mime import image
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
#     return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)


# Create your models here.
class Images(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(#upload_to=user_directory_path,
    width_field=100, height_field=100, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(help_text="Give a short description of the image", max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is the admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Images

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Images)
```

When I try to upload an image from the admin site, this is the error I get.

```
TypeError at /admin/imgUploader/images/add/
getattr(): attribute name must be string
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Django docs - [height_field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField.height_field) height field is the "Name of a **model field** which will be auto-populated with the height of the image each time the model instance is saved.".

So, `width_field=100, height_field=100,` are the codes generating this error here.

Therefore, instead of:

```
file = models.ImageField(#upload_to=user_directory_path,
width_field=100, height_field=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

Try:

```
height=models.PositiveIntegerField()

width=models.PositiveIntegerField()

file=models.ImageField(upload_to='images', height_field='height', 
 width_field='width')
```

Comment: When I try to add an image to the database from the admin page, I'm getting this error: no such column: imgUploader_images.height